# Make some but not all tabs in an UITabViewController reorderbable

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a possibility to make some but not all tabs re-orderable in an UITabbarController in iOS 12+?

I looked for a related UITabbarDelegate or an option in the storyboard but this was not a success.

MY idea was to use delegate function `func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, willBeginCustomizing items: [UITabBarItem])` and just call the super implementation with the sortable items. But this has no effect.

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController
{
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, willBeginCustomizing items: [UITabBarItem]) {
        super.tabBar(tabBar, willBeginCustomizing: [items.first!])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller).

> By default, the user is allowed to rearrange all items on the tab bar. If you do not want the user to modify some items, though, you can remove the appropriate view controllers from the array in the `customizableViewControllers` property.

Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for.